# Why do I have a wide range of BSOD errors after installing SSD and RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, bsod

I installed a new SSD and RAM in my setup yesterday night, and since this morning I've had a wide range of error messages and BSOD about every two minutes after booting into windows. Sometimes this happens almost immediately. I've included a few of them below.

> Irql_not_less_or_equal
> Kmode_exception_not_handled
> Memory_management_error
> Critical_Process_died
> Kernal_data_inpage_error
> Kernal_security_check_failure
> System_service_exception
> Page_fault_in_nonpage_area

While it BSODs at what seems like random points, it consistently does so when booting into a game.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Apologies for not including any debug data or anything, not sure what is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 99% Probability of a bad or badly seated RAM module (DIMM).

Comment: @eugen I've tried reseating it and using the other DIMM slot, no dice

Comment: I've tried my old ram as well, but that no longer seems to work?

Comment: Remove the RAM slot and test it for a few hours/days. That will almost surely make the errors go away, which would show that the culprit is the RAM and the SSD has no part on that. Then you can try getting that module to work reseating, etc. It might even be a faulty module.

Answer (score 1):

*System_service_exception Page_fault_in_nonpage_area*  The non-page area refers to the non-page pool of RAM. This is where the system stores the critical information necessary to function on the RAM, the stuff that cannot get moved out when it isn't being used, like a movie would be. I agree that you RAM is somehow the issue.